# NETStandard 1.3 compatibility with NetCoreApp1.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm getting the following error when trying to `dotnet restore`:

> Package Amazon.Lambda.Core 1.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp10 (netcoreapp1.0,Version=v0.0). Package Amazon.Lambda.Core 1.0.0 supports: netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
>   (edited)

but I want to interpret the [implementation support table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) so that netstandard 1.3 *is* supported under netcoreapp1.0.

Is this supposed to work, or not? If not, what combination of target framework and SDK should I use to be able to reference that package?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To avoid errors like this double-check the syntax of the target framework. Be aware that:

- `<TargetFramework>` (singular) is only used for a single target framework, e.g. `netcoreapp1.0`.
- `<TargetFrameworks>` (plural) can be used for multiple frameworks, separated by semicolon (`;`) - e.g. `netcoreapp1.0;netcoreapp2.0`.

It looks like there is a typo in your project file and the dot in `1.0` is missing and `netcoreapp10` is not correctly interpreted by nuget - hence the `v0.0` in the string.

Check that your project's target framework is `netcoreapp1.0`

Comment: I had, naïvely, tried to add `netcoreapp1.0` to my `<TargetFramework>` node, rather than just set the value. When I set the value to exactly `netcoreapp1.0` (and not e.g. `netcoreapp1.0,netcoreapp2.0`) it works. (Well, I get a different error because some package down the line references NETStandard.Library 1.6.1, but that's a different issue...)

Comment: so you used `<TargetFramework>` instead of `<TargetFrameworks>` (plural) and `,` instead of `;`? that's bad..

Comment: Yes, apparently it is. But knowing how to fix it, it now works with multiple target frameworks, too. Thanks!